# Unable to find matches using email regular expression with unicode characters

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

we've got `regular expression` which is used on our backend for email validation:

> /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'*+-/=\?\^*`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))).)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i

I tested it using online tool, works fine:

https://regexr.com/3u9tn

However, I have some difficulties using it in our `swift` project. I had to escape special characters and wrap all unicode characters into {} to use as a `swift` string literal.

Here is playground:

```
import Foundation

let pattern = "/^((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])*([a-z]|\\d|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])|(([a-z]|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])*([a-z]|[\u{00A0}-\u{D7FF}\u{F900}-\u{FDCF}\u{FDF0}-\u{FFEF}])))$/i"

extension String {
    func matches(_ pattern: String) -> Bool {
        do {
            let internalExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .allowCommentsAndWhitespace)
            let matches = internalExpression.matches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion, range:NSMakeRange(0, self.count))
            return matches.count > 0
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
            return false
        }
    }
}

let matches = "test@gmail.com".matches(pattern)
print(matches)
```

I tried different match options but still getting error and I'm a bit confused now how to make this work:

> The value
>   “/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'*+-/=\?\^*`{\|}~]|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])|(\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])|(([a-z]|\d|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])*([a-z]|\d|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯]))).)+(([a-z]|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])|(([a-z]|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])([a-z]|\d|-|.|_|~|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])*([a-z]|[ -퟿豈-﷏ﷰ-￯])))$/i”
>   is invalid.

I have checked already similar questions and my question is not about which `regular expression` to use but how to make this one working since I'd like to keep it consistent

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of changes you need to make to have the pattern work with ICU regex engine (ICU library provides regex capabilities in Swift/Objective-C).

- Wrapping `\uXXXX` with `\u{XXXX}` is wrong, you just need to double escape the backslash as ICU regex supports `\uXXXX` notation
- Do not escape chars that do not need escaping inside a character class (only escape `\`, `[` and `]`, others can be easily placed inside without escaping, e.g. `-` should be put at the start/end of the character class)
- Merge the separate character classes since they all match one single char (i.e. `([a-c]|[e-g]|\d)` = `[a-ce-g\d]`)
- `(\x22)`: no need using a capturing group to wrap a single atom, remove parentheses in such cases (a grouping is needed when you want to match several sequences or alternatives)
- `(\x20|\x09)*`: single char matching atoms should be grouped as a character class for better efficiency, `[\x20\x09]*`

You may use (after double escaping)

```
^([-a-z\d!#\$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[-a-z\d!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|(\x22((([\x20\x09]*\x0d\x0a)?[\x20\x09]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([\x20\x09]*\x0d\x0a)?[\x20\x09]+)?\x22))@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][-a-z\d._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][-a-z\d._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))$
```

Like this:

```
let str = "дима@gmail.com"
let pattern = "(?i)^([-a-z\\d!#\\$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]+(\\.[-a-z\\d!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]+)*|(\\x22((([\\x20\\x09]*\\x0d\\x0a)?[\\x20\\x09]+)?([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7e\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))*(([\\x20\\x09]*\\x0d\\x0a)?[\\x20\\x09]+)?\\x22))@(([a-z\\d\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]|([a-z\\d\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF][-a-z\\d._~\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]*[a-z\\d\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))\\.)+([a-z\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]|([a-z\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF][-a-z\\d._~\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]*[a-z\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))$"
print(str.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil) // => true
```

Note that `(?i)` turns on case insensitivity for the regex.